# How to create war files from gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp, war

I am working on one angular project where all angular files and html in **/src/app** folder and there is gulp folder which create the environment

now I want to create *`.war`* files for apache tomcat with help of gulp but do not understand how to achieve this

when I use `gulp serve:dist` it creates **dist** folder and **.tmp** folder above the app. below is complete tree

```
|-- bower_components
|-- bower.json
|-- dist
|-- gulp
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- node_modules
|-- package.json
|-- README.md
|-- src
```

**dist** folder tree structure is below

```
 |-- assets
    |-- favicon.ico
    |-- fonts
    |-- index.html
    |-- maps
    |-- scripts
        |-- app-4c451c4900.js
        `-- vendor-96995b9d6e.js
    `-- styles
        |-- app-1060af3936.css
        `-- vendor-7b579e8106.css
```

and here  this index.html has minified html

#### /dist/index.html

```
 <!doctype html><html ng-app="app"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><base href="/"><title ng-bind="state.current.data.pageTitle"></title><meta name="description" content="ProjectName"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory --><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor-7b579e8106.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-1060af3936.css"></head><body ng-controller="MainController as main"><!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]--><div ng-include="'app/views/common/content.html'"></div><script src="scripts/vendor-96995b9d6e.js"></script><script src="scripts/app-4c451c4900.js"></script></body></html>
```

here you can see it is using *app/views/common/content.html* for main html and only having 2 js and 2 css files

and the **.tmp** folder has below structure

```
|-- partials
|   `-- templateCacheHtml.js
`-- serve
    |-- app
    |   `-- index.css
    `-- index.html
```

#### .tmp/serve/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title ng-bind="state.current.data.pageTitle"></title>
    <meta name="description" content="ProjectName">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/roboto-fontface/css/roboto-condensed/roboto-condensed-fontface.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>
     <body ng-controller="MainController as main" >
        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
           <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div ng-include="'app/views/common/content.html'"></div>

    <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/pace/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-confirm-modal/angular-confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-validate/dist/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-sweetalert/dist/ngSweetAlert.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-sweetalert/dist/ngSweetAlert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/sockjs/sockjs.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/stomp-websocket/lib/stomp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/ng-stomp/src/ng-stomp.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- inject:vendor -->
    <script src="libs/FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/aws-sdk-2.4.8.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="app/index.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/user/user.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/key.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/auth.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app/main/main.controller.js"></script>    
    <script src="app/index.run.js"></script>
    <script src="app/index.config.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.interceptor.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.constant.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->


    <!-- inject:partials -->
    <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

     </body>
     </html>
```

`gulp serve:dist` task has below code

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
  ])
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeScriptTypeAttributes : true
    }))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'app',
      root: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });
  var assets;

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe(assets = $.useref.assets())
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.cleanCss({ processImport: false }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeScriptTypeAttributes : true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
  });

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task


gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe($.filter('**/*.{otf,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function () {
  var fileFilter = $.filter(function (file) {
    return file.stat.isFile();
  });

  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js,less}')
  ])
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});


gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')]);
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);

gulp.task('war', ['html', 'fonts', 'other'], function () {
    gulp.src([
        path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/**'),
        path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/**')
        ])
        .pipe($.war({
            welcome: 'index.html',
            displayName: 'MY Project',
        }))
        .pipe($.zip('myProject.war'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});

gulp.task('build', ['war']);
```

Here I added code to create .war files but it does not create proper folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by doing this

first remove html5 mode from *index.config.js*

```
// $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and add `<base hreaf="/myProject">` in *app/index.html*
  and than run

```
gulp.task('war', ['html', 'fonts', 'copyfonts', 'other'], function () {
    gulp.src([
        path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/**')
        ])
        .pipe($.war({
            welcome: 'index.html',
            displayName: 'My Project',
        }))
        .pipe($.zip('myProject.war'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')));
});
```

hope it helps someone